# How to attach event handler to ExtJs Component before it is created

Tags: extjs4

I know something about DOM query but this won't help me solving this problem.
I need to attach multiple events to multiple text fields  in application launch Extjs 4.
How do i do that?

Comment: Did you read documentation before posting question here ?

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260134/extjs-4-event-handling-tutorial and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225389/how-do-i-attach-an-event-handler-to-a-panel-in-extjs

Comment: i have read it ,can you help me Snake Eyes.i need to attach events to all current n future generated text field using class name(components  not dom elements )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign event handlers to dom elements before the elements are created then you can use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8081472/842075.

If you want to assign event handlers to components before the components are created then all you need is [Ext.app.EventBus.controll](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/source/EventBus.html#Ext-app-EventBus-method-control) method (it is used internally by mvc controllers):

```js
var listeners = {
    'textfield[cls="mycls"]': {
        change: function() { alert('textfield with cls="mycls" changed'); }
    }
};
Ext.app.EventBus.control(listeners, scopeObject);
```

Note that `Ext.app.EventBus` is not present in sencha docs. The examples of usage of `control` method may be found in documentation for [Ext.app.Controller.control](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-control) method.

Here's [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/pkWS5/).

If you are using extjs mvc than just use [Ext.app.Controller.control](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-control) method.