# EXT JS 4 MVC click event on a div

Tags: javascript, extjs, dom-events, extjs-mvc

I was wondering if it's possible to catch a click event on a certain div from the controller in an EXT JS 4 MVC app.

Lets say we have:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.myController', {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
init : function() {
    this.control({
        '#myDiv' : {
                     event: this.myFunction
                     }
    });
}
 myFunction: function() {...} });
```

When I click on myDiv I want to call myFunction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047862/attach-extjs-mvc-controllers-to-dom-elements-not-components/7535128

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attach ExtJS MVC controllers to DOM elements, not components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047862/attach-extjs-mvc-controllers-to-dom-elements-not-components)