# ExtJS 4.1: unload event

Tags: extjs, dom-events, extjs4.1

I am working with ext js 4.1. I am developing an application that have to support IE9, the latest Firefox, the latest Chrome and Safari.

I need to show an alert message when the user wants to leave the if there are some data that is pending to submit.

I did the following using raw Javascript:

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(){
    if (Ext.getStore('LocalChangesStore')){
        if (Ext.getStore('LocalChangesStore').getCount() > 0) {
            return 'Your changes are be lost.'; 
        } 
    }
};
```

I am wondering if that would be possible with ext js. I saw the following function:

*app.js:*

```
EventManager.onWindowUnload( function(){
    if (Ext.getStore('LocalChangesStore')){
        if (Ext.getStore('LocalChangesStore').getCount() > 0) {
            return 'Your changes are be lost.'; 
        } 
    }        
    }, this
);
```

but it did not work.

Can somebody let me know which would be the best approach to solve this issue?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047862/attach-extjs-mvc-controllers-to-dom-elements-not-components

Answer (score 8):

The **onWindowUnload** method attachs a function to the unload event but what you need is attach a function to the **beforeunload** event. Try this please

```
Ext.EventManager.on(window, 'beforeunload', function() {
    return 'Your changes are be lost.';
});
```

Good luck.

Comment: Dous no longer work in Chrome! event gets ignored as  of 7.19.2016