# Registering events works only first time

Tags: extjs

I have a window, and inside it a panel. The panel contains text (basic html). After the window is ready I call the following function, which finds elements with specific class, and registers *click* events on them. This works at first.

After closing the window, and recreating 1:1 similar window the events will not fire. The same happens if I .update() the panel and re-run my function - the events fail to fire. **Why is this?**

I can still see elements being found, and apparently some events must be registered, but my clicks can't be captured by the debug code, or the receiving function anymore.

```
addEvents: function(win) {
    // The Window
    var ow = win;

    // Using this debug trick I can see that on the second time the events wont fire
    // -- nothing gets printed to console 
    Ext.util.Observable.capture(ow, function(){
        console.log(arguments);
    });

    // Will search for elements, finds elements that have class myclass
    // In my case the elements are just ordinary html tags in the visible content
    // area of the panel.
    var elems = ow.down('panel').getEl().select(".myclass").elements;

    Ext.Array.forEach(elems, function (item, index, allItems) {
        // We need Ext DOM element to be able to attach stuff to it
        var elem = new Ext.dom.Element(item);
        elem.on ('click', function (evt, el, o) {
            ow.fireEvent('myevent', ow, elem);
        });
    });
}
```

I suspected at first that I have to actually unregister the previous events and destroy the window, so I tried adding this to the *close* of the window:

```
    window.down('panel').destroy();
    window.destroy();
```

However it seems I have some other problem I really am unable to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very JQuery-ish way to add events. You are dealing with components and should add event listeners on components. If you need to delegate events down to html elements then you need to set a single event listener on the Component encapsulating the elements and add delegate config to the actual html elements.

Here are some resources:
[Explain ExtJS 4 event handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260134/extjs-4-event-handling-tutorial)

Event delegation explained:
http://www.sencha.com/blog/event-delegation-in-sencha-touch (applies to extjs just as well)

More on Listeners with extjs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8733338/834424

Comment: This is very interesting. I can see that the delegation method works properly, and I can also see that it is better engineering in any case. However, could you please still explain (like I'm five) what exactly broke my original solution?

Comment: It's difficult to say, the code seems to be OK. There maybe issues with Ext DOM wrappers, cached HTML fragments, etc. What you can do is in firebug right click on the html element (inside HTML tab) and click Log Events option. See if browser is firing events there.